# Looping in Java and getting the sum without using any buitin function

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, math

I have a problem which I am trying to solve. The work is like:

The user will input a number say 5 and the output will be

```
Output:
5 55 555 5555 55555
sum: 61725
```

Another example,

```
Input: 4
Output: 
4 44 444 4444
sum: 4936
```

I have displayed the series but can't do the sum.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input: ");
    int in = input.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Output: ");

    for(int i=1;i<=in;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            System.out.print(in);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");  
    }
```

this will print the series. You can change the whole code, no problem. Just CAN'T use any builtin function like `Math.pow()` etc.

I was thinking of using :

```
for(int a=1;a<=in;a++){ 
    f=f*10+in; sum+=f; 
}
```

Comment: Why would you use Math.pow anyway? What other functions can't you use?

Comment: Have you, you know, *tried* to add the values to the sum? Because you don't even touch the sum variable in the code you posted other than to declare it.

Comment: That's the problem. I am not getting it how to sum

Comment: System.out.print is a builtin function, though... So is input.nextInt

Comment: No we can use that

Comment: Just as well.  It is impossible to use get input without using built-in functions.  :-)

Comment: Other packages like math etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String#repeat` function and parse it to integer. At every loop you would have to append it to sum:

```
sum = sum + Integer.valueOf(("" + in).repeat(in));
```

Without using ANY build-in functions, we have to notice, that in the sum `in` appears `in` times, `10 * in` - `(in - 1)` times and so on (`sum = in * in + 10 * in * (in - 1) + ...`), hence you can use the following loop:

```
int sum = 0;
int currentIn = in;
for(int i = 0; i < in; i++) {
    sum = sum + (in - i) * currentIn;
    currentIn = currentIn * 10;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Notice this does it with single loop.

Comment: That is using builtin functions.

Comment: @StephenC right, I thought it's about `math` package. Corrected, thank you.

Comment: Sum is unexpected !

Answer (score 2):

```
int in = ...

int sum = 0;
int term = in;
for (int i = 0; i < in; i++) {
    sum += term;
    term = 10 * term + in;
}
```

The point is that you can compute the series 4, 44, 444, ... by simple arithmetic and a loop.

But note that this will break for large values of `in` for two reasons.

*Challenge:  See if you can figure out what they are!*

Answer (score 1):

Try the below implementation:

```
long sum = 0;
String num;
 for(int i=1;i<=in;i++){
    num = ""; //re-initialize number
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
     num += in; //keep track of every individual number
        System.out.print(in);
    }
    System.out.print(" ");  
   //sum up each number after space
   sum += Integer.parseInt(num);
  }
  System.out.print("sum: " + sum);
```

Comment: parseInt() can't be used

Answer (score 1):

isnt it rather simple?

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input: ");
    int in = input.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    int product=1;

    System.out.println("Output: ");

    for(int i=1;i<=in;i++){
        for(int j=0,prod=in;j<i;j++){
            System.out.print(in);
            prod=(j>0)?(prod*10)+in:prod;
        }
        sum+=prod;
        System.out.print(" ");  
    }
    System.out.println("sum: "+sum);
```

Comment: 5+55+555+5555+55555= 61725

Comment: Dude! satisfy yourself first.. check the code then submit here.. sum not as expected !!